# xslt - only search xml at a particular node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

given:

```
<document>
  <xmlNode>Not important here. Sample 1.</xmlNode>
  <xmlNode>Not important here. Sample 2.</xmlNode>
  <xmlNode>Not important here. Sample 3.</xmlNode>
  <target><variable><number/><ofdescendants><findme/></ofdescendants></variable>Find something in here only.</target>
  <xmlNode>Not important here. Sample 5.</xmlNode>
  <xmlNode>Not important here. Sample 6.</xmlNode>
</document>
```

Using **xslt**, how would I match on an element that can appear anywhere in the target's descendants?

Comment: Did you try `<xsl:template match="/document/target">`? Actually what did you try?

Comment: What do you mean by "search"?  That's not an XSLT concept.  Are you trying to write one or more location paths that match only `<target>` and its descendants?  Are you trying to write a transform that transforms only that subtree?  Maybe something else?

Comment: I'm trying to create <xsl:template match="?? as mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I match on an element that can appear anywhere in the target's descendants?

A location path that matches elements `<e>`, but only in the subtree rooted at `/document/target`, would most readily be constructed by using the `descendant` axis, or the `descendant-or-self` axis if the `<target>` itself is to be considered a candidate:

```
/document/target/descendant::e
```

or

```
/document/target/descendant-or-self::e
```

The latter can be abbreviated as

```
/document/target//e
```

Those are all absolute location paths, or course.  You can also form relative ones, and that might be all you need.  Details depend on the overall stylesheet and the context from which those nodes will be selected for transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the extra insight